# Flask-WTF FileField does not set data attribute to an instance of Werkzeug FileStorage

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Flask-WTF's [documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form.html) states that:

> Flask-WTF provides you a FileField to handle file uploading, it will automatically draw data from flask.request.files if the form is posted. The data attribute of FileField will be an instance of Werkzeug FileStorage.

However, when I use `FileField`, the `data` attribute after posting is not a `FileStorage` object. Instead, it is either `None` (if I define my form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as suggested in the documentation) or the filename as a string (if I don't define an `enctype`).

Here is the relevant Jinja2 template:

```
{% from "_form.html" import render_field %}
{% block body %}
  <section class="page-width-container" id="offset-content">
    <div id="utility-box">
      <h1 class="utility-header">Settings</h1>
      {{ message }}
      <form action="/settings" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ render_field(form.photo) }}
        <input type="submit" class="form-action" value="Save" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
{% endblock %}
```

The _form.html macro:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <div class="field">
    {{ field.label }}
    <span class="form-input">{{ field()|safe }}</span>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class="errors">
      {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

And here is the Python:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from flask.ext.wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired

settings_bp = Blueprint('settings', __name__)

class SettingsForm(Form):
  photo = FileField('Photo', validators=[
    FileRequired('no file!'),
  ])

@settings_bp.route('/settings', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  form = SettingsForm(request.form)
  form.validate_on_submit()
  print(type(form.photo.data))
  return render_template('settings.html', form=form, message=form.photo.data)
```

With the `enctype` attribute on the `form` element, the printed type is `NoneType`; without the `enctype` attribute, the printed type is `unicode`. Neither is the `FileStorage` object advertised by the documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I looked into the source code (`form.py`) and figured out the issue: the code to replace the default data attribute with the `FileStorage` object is not activated if the form is initialized with a specific `formdata`. The `formdata` must be left unspecified in order for the file functionality to work. Replacing this line:

```
form = SettingsForm(request.form)
```

With this line:

```
form = SettingsForm()
```

Resolved the issue.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answers. I can not find the spot you refer to in the source of form.py. Do you have a bit more details ?

Comment: @KevinLEGOFF not OP but I believe they are talking about [this part](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/6bf90327937c9e7ea5faadeb5219fc77f269c314/flask_wtf/form.py#L55-L66)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this problem was driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to clearing the passed form data
from `form = SettingsForm(request.form)` to `form = SettingsForm()`

is to pass both the `request.form` *and* the `request.files` as suggested by the [flask-wtf documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html#module-flask_wtf.file) .

```python
from flask import request
from werkzeug.datastructures import CombinedMultiDict

form = SettingsForm(CombinedMultiDict((request.files, request.form)))
```