# FileField in flask_wtf.file is not instance of werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am working on a flask form which has an image upload field, when I submit the form the `data` attribute of this `FileField` is set to `None`. As per the flask documentation.

> The FileField provided by Flask-WTF differs from the WTForms-provided
>   field. It will check that the file is a non-empty instance of
>   FileStorage, otherwise data will be None.

So I checked in my code for this `isinstance(form.profile_picture, FileStorage)` and this returns `false`.

Below are the relevant code snips

**Forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import PasswordField, StringField, SubmitField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, EqualTo, length
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed

class EditProfileForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    about_me = TextAreaField('About Me', validators=[DataRequired(),
                                                     length(min=10, max=1000)])
    profile_picture = FileField('Profile Picture', validators=[FileAllowed([
        'jpg', 'png'])])
    update = SubmitField('Update')
```

**views.py**

```
@user.route("/edit_profile/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_profile():
    form = EditProfileForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first()
        user.username = form.username.data
        user.about_me = form.about_me.data
        # if form.profile_picture.data: # this returns None
        #     user.profile_pic = process_image(form.profile_picture.data,
        #                                      user.username)
        print(isinstance(form.profile_picture, FileStorage))
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("user.profile", uname=current_user.username))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.username.data = current_user.username
        form.about_me.data = current_user.about_me
    return render_template('user/user_edit_profile.html', form=form)
```

So am I missing something here ? I have also gone through this question [Flask-WTF FileField does not set data attribute to an instance of Werkzeug FileStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203343/flask-wtf-filefield-does-not-set-data-attribute-to-an-instance-of-werkzeug-files) but this was not the issue in my case, as I have not initialized the form with any data.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this was quite simple, I didn't mentioned the correct encoding type in my `form` in the template file.

This fixed my problem.

`<form method='POST' action='' enctype=multipart/form-data>`